# WPF MVVM - How do I bind a radio button to a property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a gender property:

```
public string Gender
{
    get { return _gender; }
    set
    {
        _gender = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And two radio buttons to select two available genders:

```
 <RadioButton  GroupName="Group1" Content="Male"/>
 <RadioButton  GroupName="Group1" Content="Female"/>
```

what I  wanted to do was to set the gender string to either Male or Female depending on which radio button is selected purely from data biding without code behind, is that possible if so can someone explain? I already did this for a textbox I'm just not sure how to go about a radio button

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/393ac5/binding-radio-buttons-using-group-property-in-wpf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to use a `RadioButton.Command` and the `RadioButton.CommandParameter`. Alternatively, but with slightly more overhead, use a `Binding` or `MultiBinding` with a `IValueConverter`.

Also, you should not handle plain strings. Better define an `enum` e.g. `Gender`:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<StackPanel>
  <RadioButton Command="{Binding SetGenderCommand}"
               CommandParameter="{x:Static local:Gender.Male}" />
  <RadioButton Command="{Binding SetGenderCommand}"
               CommandParameter="{x:Static local:Gender.Female}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Raises PropertyChanged
  public Gender Gender { get; set; }

  public ICommand SetGenderCommand => new RoutedCommand(ExecuteSetGenderCommand);

  private void ExecuteSetGenderCommand(object commandParameter)
    => this.Gender = (Gender)commandParameter;
}
```

**Gender.cs**

```
public enum Gender
{
  Default = 0,
  Female,
  Male
}
```

Comment: "The simplest solution" - very subjective statement.

Comment: Yes it is, indeed...

Comment: I wonder that you didn't complain that I haven't defined the `Gender` enum using the FlagsAttribute.

Comment: it seems your ability to over-engineer things is more developed than mine. "define the Gender enum using the FlagsAttribute" - I didn't foresee such twist.

Comment: Over-engineering - that's good. Imagine a compiler that checks your code for political correctness. Would be nice to join the Roslyn team just to implement this kind of Easter eggs. Like how many developers, especially beginners like students, create a Person class? *"CS6666: A type Person is not allowed to be tested for equality. The equality operator is not meant to discriminate a Person."*...